# Term structure used in Geometric Brownian Motions under Risk Neutral Measure?

Tags: brownian-motion, risk-neutral-measure, term-structure, vasicek

When using a GBM under a risk-neutral measure to simulate stock prices, we have to use the risk-free interest rate, but how exactly do you determine what interest rate to use?

I have used the Vasicek model to price ZCB and create the term structure. So when simulating the stock prices should I use a constant risk-free rate or should it be time-dependent and follow the term structure?
I was thinking it would be more correct to use the forward rate as the risk-free rate for each time period.

Comment: I agree with your suggestion to use the correct forward rate for each period.

Comment: You need to use the short rate as described by the Vasicek model. Just simulate GBM and the Vasicek model jointly.

Answer (score 2):

It should be time dependent and set to the spot forward rate $= -\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \ln(\text{discount}(t))$ when simulating in continuous time. When discretizing the simulation use the forward rate $= -\frac{\ln(\text{discount}(t_{i+1})) - \ln(\text{discount}(t_{i}))}{t_{i+1} - t_{i}}$ from one time pillar $t_i$ to the next time pillar $t_{i+1}$.